# I have problem understanding the std::cin.peek() and std::cin.get()

Tags: c++, io, get, inputstream

I am so confused about the usage of `std::cin.peek()`, `std::cin.get()` I mean these versions returning an `int`.

As I've read on C++ primer we should never assign the return from these function to a `char`:

```
char c = std::cin.get(); // erroneous
```

But on Cppreference it does it in the example and in many websites and many programmers including me until I discovered the logic of not doing so.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

And I see also such usage checking for a new line:

```
while(std::cin.peek() != '\n' )
    ;// do something
```

In the above code I think it is OK because in fact there is no assignment from `int` to `char` but a comparison in which the newline character `'\n'` is promoted first to `int` then compared with `int` which I think is not evil.

- If the code is OK then what is the point in using `std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type()` function?
- So there is no way to assign any value returned from `peek()` and `get()` to a `char`?'

I've seen some recommended code like:

```
char c;
while(std::cin.peek() != std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type('\n')){
    std::cin.get(c);
    std::cout.put(c);
}
```

- So what is the difference between implicit conversion of `'\n'` to `int` and using this trait function?

Comment: These functions are returning an `int` and not `char` in order to be able to return `eof()` (which is commonly defined as -1). Basically, they need a return type that can represent any `char` value, plus one more value. It is safe to convert the result back to `char` if you have reasons to believe that the file is not at EOF, but generally you'd want to check for that first.

Comment: Alternatively, use an overload that takes `char` as a parameter by reference, e.g. `char ch; while (std::cin.get(ch)) { ... }`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But sometimes we need to use peek() because we only want to check the next character in the input stream without extracting it. which doesn't have an overload that dakes argument like get()

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But here std::cin.peek() != '\n' is not converting a char to int but on contrary promoting character '\n' to int.

Comment: So use `peek()` if you need to. Be aware that it, too, may return `eof()`, and that `eof() != '\n'`. I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty. Is there anything else you would like clarification on?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah! so you mean that the return value from peek maybe eof and '\n' may has the same negative value on some implementations in which case the loop may loop infinitely or prematurely stops execution? that is why I need the trait function to_int_type() right?

Comment: So, `char` may be signed or unsigned; it's implementation-defined. `std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type()` would map any `char` value to a value distinct from `eof()` (commonly implemented as `int(unsigned char(ch))`, always positive, while `eof()` is usually -1). `char_traits::to_char_type` converts in the other direction; the result of `char_traits::to_char_type(eof())` is unspecified. (continued)

Comment: `to_char_type` may not be as simple as `char(int_val)` - e.g. when `char` is signed, `int_val` may exceed the largest value representable in `char`, and a signed integer overflow exhibits either undefined or unspecified behavior (I always forget which). So `char ch = cin.peek();` is not strictly valid, but works in practice for plain 7-bit ASCII characters, as well as high ASCII characters on a typical two's complement machine (where signed integer overflow behaves predictably). Except that you cannot reliably detect from `ch` whether `peek()` returned `eof()`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you get it now. would you add your comments as answer? this will help someone else.

Comment: Technically, `char_traits<char>::to_int_type('\n')` may not be equal to `int('\n')` even if you know that `'\n'` is a positive value. `to_int_type()` may perform an arbitrarily complex mapping, as long as it's reversible by `to_char_type` (e.g. `int(unsigned char(ch))*10` is a valid implementation). So in principle, `cin.peek() != '\n'` is invalid; in practice, it would work with any sane implementation.